# Change Domain Field of Layer

Tags: qgis, domains

Is there a possibility to change the Domain Field Values after saved in the QGIS geopackage?

Here I have e.g. a geopackage and set up a new domain *rightclick .gpkg in Browser* -> *New Domain*:
[image]

**How can I add e.g. *Type 4* to the Values after saving the domain?**

Comment: So long story short: There is no built-in QGIS editor that lets you edit the domain after saving it. Thats a bit odd. Thank you anyway. I will try the SQL-Part when I are more experienced :) @J.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to modify the domain after creation but it's not straightforward, in your exemple it will probably be simpler to just delete the domain and recreate it. That being said, to modify a GPKG domain you need to modify the table that store the domain information, to do that :

- Make a copy of your GPKG as a backup if something go wrong
- in QGIS open the DB manager (in the menu : Database > DB
  manager or add the database toolbar and click on the database icon)
- In the provider panel of the BD manager right click on SpatiaLite and choose "New
  connection..." then navigate to your geopackage and select it. You
  want to add a SpatiaLite connection rather than the more logical
  GeoPackage connection to be able to look at system table. The procedure will
  work the same if you add a GeoPackage connection, you just wont be able to check table or field name or to see what your domain currently look like.
- Select the connection corresponding to your geopackage and open the
  SQL window (menu : Database > SQL Window or click on the wrench icon)
- To add a new domain value (in your exemple 'Type 4') enter the
  following SQL and click the Execute button

  INSERT INTO "gpkg_data_column_constraints" (constraint_name, constraint_type,
  value, description) values ('Type', 'enum', 'Type 4',
  'Type 4');

or in a more general way

```
INSERT INTO "gpkg_data_column_constraints" (constraint_name, constraint_type, value, description)
VALUES ('Domain name', 'enum', 'Domain code', 'Domain description');
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response @J.R . That makes sense. So we change with SQL the intern table for the domain programmically. So in theory QGIS could implement this if they would create sort of a Qt Button and connect it the code you provided. So this would be user friendly :)

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/55257