# Editing file geodatabase domain using QGIS

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, domains

I noticed that I can now create domains in FGDBs in QGIS.

Once I have created one, is there a way to add a value other than to delete and re-create the domain?

Comment: As the way to do it for gpkg is not that simple (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470048/change-domain-field-of-layer/470067#470067) when gpkg is the default fomat for QGIS I don't think it will be easier for gdb...