# QGIS - GeoPackage domains: edit & import/export

Tags: qgis, geopackage, domains

How can I a) edit existing domains from GeoPackage files in QGIS and b) export and import them, e.g. as CSV files?

Is there a plugin for this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question.  Please [Edit] your question to focus on one task, and state what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Does this answer a) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470048/change-domain-field-of-layer? Export should possible at least with generic SQLite tools. Have a look at "gpkg_data_column_constraints" and "gpkg_data_columns".